How to uninstall AdGuard Network System Extension - version 2.8.1
Despite repeated attempts of following the official guide, as well as researching the internet, I cannot successfully uninstall the system extension, and it keeps re-appearing in EtreCheck reports:
System Extensions:
[Blocked] AdGuard Network Extension - version 2.8.1 (Adguard Software Limited)
Application: /Applications/Adguard.app - version 2.8.1 (Not found!)
Description: AdGuard Network Extension
I cannot identify the remaining files on the computer that indicate the system extension is present. Each new report does indicate this issue despite that. Perhaps there is an operation needed on root, not user?
I am on MacOS 14.4.1 and this system extension has been lingering on system for almost 2 years.

System extensions are in /Library/SystemExtensions. I believe (can't check) that you can use systemextensionsctl list to discover the bundleID and then sudo systemextensionsctl uninstall <bundleID>. If it objects about SIP, you will need to go into recovery mode, disable SIP, reboot and try again.

@Gilby I found the extension there as you said. It objects for SIP. Do I have to disable all of them, or just any particular one/s?

For SIP, easiest just to disable everything.  When you are finished you can enable SIP again.

In System Settings > Privacy & Security, you may see an item for the AdGuard extension showing that it's blocked, even though it's no longer installed. If so, click the Allow button. The entry should then be removed. I have no idea what "Etrecheck" does, and if the only problem is some warning it's giving you, then I suggest you just get rid of it. Third-party "utilities" are not needed on a Mac.

Start here https://etrecheck.com/en/index.html to learn about EtreCheck. It is a handy way of discovering potentially bad things.
